# Как добавить исключение в SQL запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, у меня есть SQL запрос, который связывает 2 таблицы
Нужно сделать ограничение на вывод, то есть если orders.paid = 1 тогда выводим, как реализовать, вот сам запрос

```
 $history = mysql_query("
 SELECT orders.name, orders.email, orders.paid
 FROM user
 INNER JOIN orders
 ON user.userEmail = orders.email
 ORDER BY user.userEmail;
 ");
```

Comment: Вопросами вывода занимается клиентская часть, а не SQL-сервер.

Comment: @Akina как можно реализовать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT orders.name, orders.email, orders.paid
 FROM user, orders
 WHERE user.userEmail = orders.email and orders.paid = 1 
 ORDER BY user.userEmail
```

Связывать юзвера по email конечно можно, но лучше зделать auto-id, ну не любяд БД строковых ключей...

Избегайте использования JOIN без годной на то необходимости.